# Three Haskell functions to show filtered results from a list of films

Tags: beginner, haskell

I'm currently working on a simple command line application in Haskell and I have three functions that are quite repetitive.

The three functions:

```
getAllFilmsByDirector :: [Film] -> String -> String
getAllFilmsByDirector filmsDb directorName = unlines [name ++ ", " ++ director ++ ", " ++ show year ++ ", " ++ show (calculateRatings likes dislikes)|(name, director, year, likes, dislikes) <- filmsDb, director == directorName]

getAllFilmsWithHighRatings :: [Film] -> String
getAllFilmsWithHighRatings filmsDb = unlines [name ++ ", " ++ director ++ ", " ++ show year ++ ", " ++ show (calculateRatings likes dislikes)|(name, director, year, likes, dislikes) <- filmsDb, (calculateRatings likes dislikes) >= 75]

getAllFilmsByDirectorAvgRating :: [Film] -> String -> Float
getAllFilmsByDirectorAvgRating filmsDb directorName = roundTo (calculateAverageRating [calculateRatings likes dislikes|(name, director, year, likes, dislikes) <- filmsDb, director == directorName]) 1
```

**Film Type**

```
type Film = (String, String, Int, [String], [String])

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner", "Ridley Scott", 1982, ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Kate", "Emma", "Liz", "Dave"], ["Sam", "Olga", "Tim"]), ("The Fly", "David Cronenberg", 1986, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe"], ["Kevin", "Emma", "Heidi", "Jo", "Kate"]), ("Body Of Lies", "Ridley Scott", 2008, ["Garry", "Dave"], ["Bill", "Olga", "Tim", "Zoe", "Paula"]), ("Avatar", "James Cameron", 2009, ["Dave", "Amy", "Liz"], ["Olga", "Tim", "Zoe", "Paula"]), ("Titanic", "James Cameron", 1997, ["Zoe", "Emma", "Paula", "Liz", "Olga", "Dave"], ["Sam", "Wally", "Kate"]), ("The Departed", "Martin Scorsese", 2006, ["Wally", "Liz", "Kevin", "Tim", "Emma"], ["Olga", "Dave", "Kate", "Zoe"]), ("Aliens", "Ridley Scott", 1986, ["Dave", "Garry", "Liz", "Sam", "Wally", "Kate", "Zoe"], ["Tim", "Emma", "Jo", "Olga"]), ("Kingdom Of Heaven", "Ridley Scott", 2005, ["Jo", "Wally", "Emma"], ["Tim", "Garry", "Ian", "Neal"]), ("Alien: Covenant", "Ridley Scott", 2017, ["Kevin", "Tim"], ["Emma", "Jo", "Liz"]),  ("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial", "Steven Spielberg", 1982, ["Dave", "Amy", "Garry", "Ian", "Neal"], ["Jenny", "Kate", "Emma", "Olga"]), ("Bridge of Spies", "Steven Spielberg", 2015, ["Wally", "Sam", "Dave", "Neal"], ["Bill", "Garry", "Ian", "Kate"]), ("Jaws", "Steven Spielberg", 1975, ["Jenny", "Emma", "Bill", "Neal"], ["Sam", "Ian", "Kate"]), ("The Martian", "Ridley Scott", 2015, ["Wally", "Sam", "Dave", "Jo", "Jenny", "Kate", "Emma", "Olga"], ["Ian", "Neal", "Tim", "Liz"]), ("The BFG", "Steven Spielberg", 2016, ["Sam", "Wally", "Dave", "Jo", "Kate"], ["Neal"]), ("The Shawshank Redemption", "Frank Darabont", 1994, ["Dave", "Amy", "Bill", "Garry", "Ian", "Neal", "Kate", "Jenny", "Zoe", "Heidi"], ["Jo"]), ("Gladiator", "Ridley Scott", 2000, ["Olga", "Neal", "Kate", "Garry"], ["Heidi", "Bill", "Sam", "Zoe"]), ("The Green Mile", "Frank Darabont", 1999, ["Kevin", "Tim", "Emma", "Heidi"], ["Kate", "Jenny", "Zoe"]), ("True Lies", "James Cameron", 1994, ["Sam", "Dave"], ["Emma", "Olga", "Jenny", "Zoe"]), ("Super 8", "J J Abrams", 2011, ["Kevin", "Tim", "Emma", "Olga", "Heidi"], ["Wally", "Dave", "Jenny", "Zoe"]), ("Minority Report", "Steven Spielberg", 2002, ["Kevin", "Kate", "Tim", "Emma", "Jenny", "Zoe"], ["Olga", "Heidi"]), ("War Horse", "Steven Spielberg", 2011, ["Garry", "Bill", "Olga", "Jo", "Wally", "Emma", "Tim", "Kate", "Zoe"], ["Heidi", "Jenny", "Sam"]), ("Silence", "Martin Scorsese", 2016, ["Wally", "Emma", "Tim", "Heidi", "Bill", "Jo"], ["Dave", "Olga"]), ("The Terminal", "Steven Spielberg", 2004, ["Kate", "Dave", "Jo", "Wally", "Emma"], ["Heidi"]), ("Star Wars: The Force Awakens", "J J Abrams", 2015, ["Emma", "Wally", "Zoe", "Kate", "Bill", "Dave", "Liz"], ["Olga", "Jo", "Neal"]), ("Hugo", "Martin Scorsese", 2011, ["Wally", "Sam"], ["Kate", "Bill", "Dave"])]
```

**roundTo**

```
roundTo x n = (fromIntegral (round (x * 10^n))) / 10^n
```

**calculateRatings**

```
calculateRatings :: [String] -> [String] -> Int
calculateRatings likes dislikes = round(fromIntegral (length likes) / fromIntegral (length likes + length dislikes) * 100)
```

**calculateAvgRating**

```
calculateAverageRating :: [Int] -> Float
calculateAverageRating rating = fromIntegral (round(fromIntegral ((foldr (+) 0 rating)) / fromIntegral (length rating) * 100)) / 100
```

I'm fairly new to Haskell and its syntax but I know I should probably make use of the `getAllFilmsByDirector` in the `getAllFilmsByDirectorAvgRating` however because the `getAllFilmsByDirectorAvgRating` takes a `Film` type rather than a string, I'm not too sure about the best way to modify the code to make use of the `getFilmsByDirector` function.

I'm also using very similar list comprehensions in each of the three and if anyone has any ideas on how I can make these less repetitive that would be amazing.

Comment: Without `Film`, `roundTo`, `calculateRatings` and `calculateAverageRating` your code isn't complete.

Comment: @Zeta Have added missing code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't repeat yourself

Your code suffers from being [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions). Your `Film`'s formatting function is repeated. So let us get rid of that first:

```
prettyFilm :: Film -> String
prettyFilm (name, director, year, likes, dislikes) =
    name ++ ", " ++ director ++ ", " ++ show year ++ ", " ++ show rating
  where rating = calculateRatings likes dislikes
```

Now `getAllFilmsByDirector` and `getAllFilmsWithHighRatings` are slightly easier to read:

```
getAllFilmsByDirector :: [Film] -> String -> String
getAllFilmsByDirector filmsDb directorName =
    unlines [prettyFilm film | film@(_, director, _, _, _) <- filmsDb
                             , director == directorName]

getAllFilmsWithHighRatings :: [Film] -> String
getAllFilmsWithHighRatings filmsDb = 
    unlines [prettyFilm film | film@(_, _, _, likes, dislikes) <- filmsDb
                             , calculateRatings likes dislikes >= 75]
```

However, that still looks like there is of duplicate code: in the end both functions filter the `filmsDb` and then print all films. If we had `getFilmsBy :: (Film -> Bool) -> [Film] -> [Film]` we could write:

```
getAllFilmsByDirector :: [Film] -> String -> String
getAllFilmsByDirector filmsDb directorName = unlines . map prettyFilm . getFilmsBy p $ filmsDb 
  where
    p (_, _, director, _, _) = director == directorName

getAllFilmsWithHighRatings :: [Film] -> String
getAllFilmsWithHighRatings filmsDb  = unlines . map prettyFilm . getFilmsBy p $ filmsDb 
  where
    p (_, _, _, likes, dislikes) = calculateRatings likes dislikes >= 75
```

Luckily, `getFilmsBy = filter`.

Now that we got rid of the list comprehensions, we can see that we can still improve our functions if we extract `unlines . map prettyFilm . filter`:

```
showAllFilmsBy :: (Film -> Bool) -> [Film] -> String
showAllFilmsBy p = unlines . map prettyFilm . filter p 

getAllFilmsByDirector :: [Film] -> String -> String
getAllFilmsByDirector filmsDb directorName = showAllFilmsBy p filmsDb
  where
    p (_, _, director, _, _) = director == directorName

getAllFilmsWithHighRatings :: [Film] -> String
getAllFilmsWithHighRatings filmsDb  = showAllFilmsBy p filmsDb
  where
    p (_, _, _, likes, dislikes) = calculateRatings likes dislikes >= 75
```

## Other review items

- Some of your parentheses are superfluous, for example those in `roundTo`. Try to get rid of those.
- Almost all your functions have type signatures (good!), except for `roundTo` (bad). Try to add type signatures to all top-level bindings.
- Unless you really need to use `Double` instead of `Float`.
- Try to stay in the original type `Film` as long as possible. You can always go from `Film` to `String`, but the inverse isn't true. That's why you couldn't reuse your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put configuration-like parameters to the left and data-like parameters to the right, it composes better.

`genericLength` condenses much conversion.

`ImplicitParams` lets me improvise a query language so I don't need to unpack the tuple everywhere.

You already wrote `roundTo` and then you didn't use it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}

getAllFilmsByDirector :: String -> [Film] -> String
getAllFilmsByDirector director = unlines . selectwhere ?pretty (?director == director)

getAllFilmsWithHighRatings :: [Film] -> String
getAllFilmsWithHighRatings = unlines . selectwhere ?pretty (?rating >= 0.75)

getAllFilmsByDirectorAvgRating :: String -> [Film] -> Float
getAllFilmsByDirectorAvgRating director
  = roundTo 1 . liftA2 (/) sum genericLength . selectwhere ?rating (?director == director)

-- selectwhere :: Query a -> Query Bool -> [Film] -> [a]
selectwhere select cond = map (exec select) . filter (exec cond) where
  -- exec :: Query a -> Film -> a
  exec query (name, director, year, likes, dislikes) = let
    ?rating = roundTo 2 $ genericLength likes / (genericLength likes + genericLength dislikes)
    ?pretty = name ++ ", " ++ director ++ ", " ++ show year ++ ", " ++ show ?ratings
    ?director = director
    in query

roundTo n x = fromIntegral (round (x * 10^n)) / 10^n
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get this error when I try to implement your code: `parse error on input ‘?’
?rating = roundTo 2 $ genericLength likes / (genericLength likes + genericLength dislikes)
`

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to drop `ImplicitParams` on a language [tag:beginner].